# Relation not loaded with includes(:profile) if order attribute is of format "profile"."firstname" ASC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

Using the following order configuration, `includes(:profile)` don't includes the relation to the profile.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  scope :order_by, -> value { includes(:profile).reorder(value) }
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Using the following value to order all accounts works fine:

```
> Account.order_by('profiles.firstname ASC')
```

Using the following value `includes(:profile)` don't includes relation `:profile` in the query:

```
> Account.order_by('"profiles"."firstname" ASC')
```

**Any idea? I want to use the second one but without using `references(:profile)` in the scope.**

**Problem**

Some words are reserved database words and should be quoted. Not quoting used words can cause a query to fail if the word is a reserved word. Here all reserved words of Postgresql postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

**Example**

Using `user` to order entries. `user` is a reserved word in Postgresql.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The first one is the correct syntax can you explain why you prefer the second?

Comment: Some words are reserved database words and should be quoted. Not quoting words in order can cause a query to fail if the word is a reserved word. Here all reserved words of Postgresql http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: Yes I know hat reserved words are but nothing you show is reserved seems like a control issue that you should handle before passing

Answer (score 0):

Does an Account always have a Profile? If so, use an INNER JOIN:

```
> Account.joins(:profile).order('"profiles"."firstname" ASC')
```

To "eager-load" the profile association, use `preload`

```
> Account.joins(:profile).order('"profiles"."firstname" ASC').preload(:profile)
```

Here's a good explanation of preload vs eager-load vs includes: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

In short, `preload` always fires a separate query, `eager_load` always LEFT JOINS in a single query, and `includes` lets Rails decide.

Comment: yes thats true, but includes() should understand also the quoted attributes in order() and not only the unquoted attributes.

Comment: Not according to the docs: (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)
`Using where like this will only work when you pass it a Hash. For
SQL-fragments you need use references to force joined tables`

Comment: Sorry, meant to link to Section 13.2: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations